# What is the best way to get item from Set<CustomObject> into List of its attribute

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8

I have a question about finding some item inside a `Collection`, for example a `Set`.

Given a class:

```
private class User{
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

    User(Set<String> name){
        this.names = name;
    }

    public Set<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }
}
```

And this code:

```
Set<String> firstSetInside = new HashSet<>();
firstSetInside.add("someName1");
firstSetInside.add("someName2");

Set<String> secondSetInside = new HashSet<>();
secondSetInside.add("someName1");
secondSetInside.add("someName2");

User user = new User(firstSetInside);
User user2 = new User(secondSetInside);

Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<>();
userSet.add(user);
userSet.add(user2);
```

How to get all names `"someNameX"` to one list correctly?

I know that I should use lambdas but how do it correctly?

Comment: Please elaborate on what your goal is. It's not clear from the code.

Comment: _"How to get all names "someName2" to one list correctly"_ you mean get all users in which its name set contains "someName2"?

Comment: I believe the question is *How to get all names "someNameX" to one list correctly"* since in the code additions have been with a similar naming convention. Would still wait for OP to update if that's the reason the answer has been downvoted.

Comment: Yes @nullpointer, the question should be like you write. Your answer is correctly thanks a lot!

Comment: @ Hugo @ Joe C @ shmosel @ Eugene @Sotirios Delimanolis Can any of the moderators please state what is still unclear in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get a concrete list of all names from all `User` in the `userSet`, you can use:

```
List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
userSet.stream().map(User::getNames).forEach(allNames::addAll);
```

***Edit*** (*after two and a half years*):- Thanks to a downvoter to bring me back here after a long time. It makes me realize how stupid a suggestion was my answer back then. Of course, a much functional way to deal with this situation is to use `flatMap` as:

```
List<String> allNames = userSet.stream()
                               .flatMap(user -> user.getNames().stream())
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: any reason to downvote? do help me out understand what went wrong, please.

Comment: You're making an unsubstantiated assumption about what OP is trying to do. And you should use `collect()` instead of `forEach()`.

Comment: @shmosel About the assumption, I've tried to explain myself out in the comments to the question as well ...and in terms of using `collect()`, would that provide any benefits over `forEach` or are there any other reaons to point that out?

Comment: `collect()` will work for parallel streams and is the more conventional way to produce an aggregate result.

Comment: @nullpointer, mutation of list that exist outside the lambda is not required when you use collect. However, I do not find that to be a enough reason to downvote as long as you know what you are doing .

Comment: @shmosel seconding the point as stated by @ Jimmy as well, the only difference that I see in using collect and foreach  is mutation. In general performance and readability doesn't look to me as compromised in the context I've answered.

Comment: @shmosel I hope the acceptance to the answer aligns to the fact that my assumption was correct.

Comment: Very well, downvote transferred to the question.

Comment: @nullpointer this *exact* use-case is written in the documentation under `side-effects` if i remember correctly. but i did not donwvote

Comment: @Eugene thats based on the condition that `forEach` would be *modifying the underlying source of elements*

Comment: @nullpointer it's not - that would be called `non-interference`.

Comment: @Eugene I didn't get you I gues in that case. I referred [this document.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: @nullpointer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html